# replicate/mirror the web page in a browser in another program

Tags: javascript, web, https

All I want to achieve is that when I browse web page in a browser (A), there is another program (B) that replicate everything in my browser. By everything I mean user login, etc. Currently the program (B) is a electron app that simply renders web pages.

I tried to set up a mitm proxy server and load every page that my browser (A) receives from server into my program (B). But HTTPS doesn't allow a proxy in between the browser (A) and the server. So that fails.

Another approach that I can think of is to record every user action in browser (A), send them to program (B) and let program (B) perform them so it ends up with the same web page with browser (A). But that approach seems a bit dirty.

One thing to note is, if I don't have any privilege on the browser (A), but I can do what ever I want with my program (B).

I wonder if there is any other way to do this.

UPDATE: I found a relatively practical way to achieve the replication. But if anyone have a better one please also post it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, I found that you can generate a root certificate for your proxy and let browser (A) trust that certificate. Then your proxy can happily eavesdrop everything between the browser (A) and the server.